# Many-to-Many: SELECT only prints sth. out when there are users in a group

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

at first my Many-to-Many-Relationship is with the following tables:

```
+----------+      +--------------+     
| users    |      | users_groups |     +--------------+
+----------+      +--------------+     | groups       |
| user_id  |----->| user_id      |     +--------------+
| username |      | group_id     |<----| group_id     |
| realname |      +--------------+     | group_name   |
| password |                           | group_desc   |
+----------+                           +--------------+
```

Now I want to get a list/table (not a table in the DB!) of all existing groups with all the users of the specific group, something like this:

```
+---------------+--------------------------+
| group         | members                  |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| Group1        | User1, User2, User3      |
| Group2        | User3, User4, User6      |
| Group3        |                          |
+---------------+--------------------------+
```

My current MySQL code is:

```
$all_groups = mysqli_query
            ($db,
            "
            SELECT g.group_name,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.realname SEPARATOR ', ') AS users
            FROM groups g
            JOIN users_groups ug1 ON g.group_id=ug1.group_id
            JOIN users u ON ug1.user_id=u.user_id
            GROUP BY g.group_name
            "
            );
```

My current PHP-Code is:

```
while($row_all_groups = mysqli_fetch_array($all_groups)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="td_contentbar">'.$row_all_groups["group_name"].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="td_contentbar">'.$row_all_groups["users"].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

But the problem is that **if a group has no users (in users_groups-table) the group isn't shown in the list/table i have** and I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace JOIN user_groups with LEFT JOIN user_groups in your query.

Comment: I have used `SELECT g.group_name,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.realname SEPARATOR ', ') AS users FROM groups g LEFT JOIN users_groups ug1 ON g.group_id=ug1.group_id JOIN users u ON ug1.user_id=u.user_id GROUP BY g.group_name` and it did not work